# WMI-Query Powershell - Read printerport on printcluster (Windows Server 2008 R2)

Tags: powershell, printing, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-clustering

I want to get the printerport information from a printcluster on windows server 2008 r2. On a normal printserver I do this with powershell and a wmi-query, something like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -computer localhost -class "Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort" | select  HostAddress
```

This query doesn't work on a printcluster environment, with computername "localhost" I get only the local installed ports. But the queues I want are in the cluster. Also when I change the computername to the clustername this query doesn't work.

Is there a WMI class, where you can access the printerinformation like queues, driver or ports from a printcluster?

Comment: According to [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4414456d-e72b-4d62-812a-327f5d077546/wmi-request-to-get-clustered-print-server-queues?forum=winserverprint) on the Technet forums WMI won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the article!

I found a way to get the information out of the cluster. I exported the complete printserverconfiguration directly in print management with PrintBRM. The exported file with the extension ".printerExport" I extracted winzip. In the extracted folder I have now XML-Files with all information of pritnerqueues. drivers, ports...

Not the way I was looking for, but a nice workaround.